# Is it possible to register an asynchronous pluggable protocol user specific registry?

Tags: installation, registry, pluggableprotocol

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(VS.85).aspx for Async Pluggable protocols.

We currently have it working, however it requires that we write to HKey_Class_Root.  In the interest of trying to allow a non-admin install, it would be nice if we could achieve the same thing with writing to HKey_Current_User.  Simply changing the registry location doesn't appear to work, and I'm wondering if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the per machine location is follows:
HKCR\CLSID{DLL-GUID}
But the per-user location is:
HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID{DLL-GUID}